# amazon rds: How can I see how much storage is using an aurora rds instance?

Tags: amazon-rds, rds, amazon-aurora

I m testing the Aurora RDS database, and are inserting data (1TB),  and it seems to go OK.

However, I can't find how much disk storage it consumes ( for billing estimation ).

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurora does not have a notion of "disk storage". It uses a distributed volume to store your data, and what you are looking for is the Volume of that volume for your cluster. This is emitted as a Cloudwatch metrics, with the name `VolumesBytesUsed`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html

That is the same metric used in your Billing computation as well. While you are there, do check the VolumeIOPS metrics as well (read and write) as they add to your billing as well.